# Input Data using ajax to SQL Server always false (failed)

Tags: php, json, ajax

Hello guys I'm trying to input data using ajax to sql server

This is the ajax script use to input data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#pengajuan').submit(function(){
      $.ajax({
      url: 'catcha.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      // catch data
        $('[name=Seafarers]').val("");
        $('[name=date]').val("");
        $('.kontent').append('Success');
      }, 
      // jika gagal
      error: function() {
        alert("Failed");
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Then I use display error.log(e); not displaying anything. Please help me

Comment: show the code in a codeblock not as image... explain more... show more code, do you have php code that handles this post? show it

Comment: Please post a test code otherwise it would be cumbersome to edit.

Comment: please check my code update

Comment: what error you are getting in developer console please upload image for network error tab. also you can put debugger in XHR call http://devtoolsecrets.com/secret/debugging-xhr-breakpoints.html

Comment: sorry success for my problem thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the which is used to pass the from data with ajax to server

```
 $('#pengajuan').submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "catcha.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('form#formId').serialize(),

        })
        .done(function(data){
            alert(data);
             $('.kontent').append('Success');
        })
        .fail(function(){
             alert("Failed");
        });
        return false;
    });
```